# Is it possible to debug plv8 script direct from IntelIJ IDEA?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, intellij-idea, plv8

IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.3 (Community Edition)

PostgreSQL 9.6

In my java project I use plv8 scripts.

Example:

```
var oids_per_vlan_json = JSON.parse(oids_per_vlan);

var table_name = plv8.execute("SELECT get_temp_table_name() as name")[0].name; 
plv8.elog(NOTICE, " Temp table name: " + table_name);
plv8.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_name);
```

As you can see to see what happend in the  scripts I use `plv8.elog`.

OK. It's work, but ... it's not very comfortable.

Is it possible to use debug in plv8 scripts?
I mean with **breakpoints, Step-Into, Step-Out** and so on?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: Postgres 9.6 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Not sure debug in plv8 is supported at all: https://github.com/plv8/plv8/issues/131#issuecomment-237711101

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov Ok, but is it possible to edit and execute store procedure direct from IntelIJ IDEA?